# ACCESS. Почему запрос запрашивает значение из столбца так параметр

Tags: ms-access

Почему одни запросы типа `select [Forms].[Main].[Kurs] AS Kurs1, [Kurs1]*1,2 as W1` возвращают результат сразу, а другие, такого же типа, иногда запрашивают Kurs1 как параметр, с отображением окна для ввода параметра?

Comment: Значит, токен не распознаётся как имя объекта. В чём проблема - в неверном контексте или ещё в чём, надо смотреть для конкретных схемы и запроса. Попробуйте открыть запрос в конструкторе и ввести имя объекта не вручную. а через построитель.

Comment: Выражение строится через построитель с выбором поля из списка

Comment: Ну тогда выкладывайте модель. Если можно обойтись короткими инструкциями - добавляете в вопрос их. Если нет - берёте БД, удаляете всё лишнее (таблицы, формы, модули и пр.), в т.ч. и лишние данные, убеждаетесь, что проблема не пропала, и выкладываете модель куда-нибудь в доступное место. Будем смотреть...